# Hooks not working on live server

Tags: hooks

This works on my development server but does nothing on the live server:

```php
add_action('get_footer', function() { echo 'Test'; });
```

It is not specific to the get_footer hook - any hook will do! I do not have a clue where to start looking, I have searched but not found anything. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where are you putting the code in your question?

Comment: In custom plug in.

Comment: High levels of embarrassment being experienced right now. I was logged into the wrong live account.

Comment: We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

get_footer hook fires before the footer template file is loaded.

Note: This hook is best to use to set up and execute code that doesn’t get echoed to the browser until later in the page load. Anything you echo will show up before any of the markup is displayed.

Besides, make sure you call the get_footer() function in your template.

You can see the doc [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_footer/).